# Accessing C exported dll functions in c# with callbacks

Tags: c#, c, dll, callback

I am trying to make a custom OBS UI using c#. OBS is a recording/streaming software that can record windows or screen or a few other things. I found this C# wrapper
https://github.com/GoaLitiuM/libobs-sharp
but unfortunately it doesn't have the ability to record or stream so I am trying to implement that myself.

I imported obs_frontend_recording_start() and obs_frontend_recording_stop() from https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/master/UI/obs-frontend-api/obs-frontend-api.h but when I call the functions I get an error that says tried to call (func name) without callbacks.  I looked into it and tried using delegates to call these functions like so:

```
public class Recording
{
    public delegate void StartRecord();
    public delegate void StopRecord();
    public Recording()
     {
        StartRecord d1 = new StartRecord(StartRecording);
        StopRecord d2 = new StopRecord(StopRecording);

    }


    public void StartRecording()
    {
        libobs.obs_frontend_recording_start();

    }


    public void StopRecording()
    {
        libobs.obs_frontend_recording_stop();
    }
```

and then in my main program when I hit a button it should do this

```
 private void rec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Recording.StartRecord d1 = new Recording.StartRecord(StartRecording);
        Recording.StopRecord d2 = new Recording.StopRecord(StopRecording);

        if (!isRec) {
            rec.Image = Properties.Resources.RecordingOnButton_small;
            d1();
            isRec = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rec.Image = Properties.Resources.RecordOffButton_small;
            d2();
            isRec = false;
        }

    }
```

After doing this the original error about callbacks went away but I do not get any feedback or recording after stopping the recording.

EDIT: this is how I am importing the functions

```
    [DllImport(obs-frontend-api.dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void obs_frontend_recording_start();

    [DllImport(obs-frontend-api.dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void obs_frontend_recording_stop();
```

Comment: Most DLL APIs use the `StdCall` calling convention, not the `Cdecl` calling convention.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I think my problem is more than that.  i think there are just aspects of the original obs code that I am not understanding how to implement in the wrapper.  I tried changing Cdecl to StdCall and it didn't change anything but I will keep this in mind as I get further toward solving this main issue